# Get row from a nested grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, datagrid, extjs5

i have a grid nested, i want to get the row inside one of them but i cant.

This is the gridpanel code:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    renderTo: 'amenazas-grid',
    store: amenazaStore,
    width: 748,
    height: 598,
    title: '<bean:write name="informesAGRForm" property="nombreActivo"/>',
    plugins: [{
        expandOnDblClick: false,
        ptype: "subtable",
        pluginId: 'subtable',
        headerWidth: 24,
            columns: [{
            text: 'id_amenaza',
            dataIndex: 'id_amenaza',
            hidden: true,
            width: 100
        }, {
            width: 100,
            text: 'id_salvaguarda',
            dataIndex: 'id_salvaguarda'
        },
        {
            text: 'denominacion',
            dataIndex: 'denominacion',
            width: 100
        },{
            text: 'descripcion',
            dataIndex: 'descripcion',
            width: 100
        },{
            text: 'eficacia',
            dataIndex: 'eficacia',
            width: 100
        },
        ],
        getAssociatedRecords: function (record) {
            var result = Ext.Array.filter(
            salvaguardaStore.data.items,

            function (r) {
                return r.get('id_amenaza') == record.get('id');
            });
            return result;
        }
    }],
    collapsible: false,
    animCollapse: false,
    columns: [

        {
            text: 'ID',
            hidden: true,
            hideable: false,
            dataIndex: 'id'
        },   
        {
            text: 'Codigo',
            width: 50,
            sortable: true,
            hideable: false,
            dataIndex: 'codigo'
        },          
        {
            text: 'Denominación',
            width: 150,
            dataIndex: 'denominacion',
        },
        {
            text: ' Autenticidad',
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'a_riesgo'
        },
        {
            text: 'Confidencialidad',
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'c_riesgo'
        },
        {
            text: 'Integridad',
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'i_riesgo'
        },
        {
            text: 'Disponibilidad',
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'd_riesgo'
        },
        {
            text: 'Trazabilidad',
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 't_riesgo'
        },
        {
            text: 'Total',
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'total_riesgo'
        }],
        listeners: {
            'rowdblclick': function (view, record, tr, columnIndex, e) {
                var cell = e.getTarget('.x-grid-subtable-cell');
                if (!cell) {
                    return;
                }
                var row = Ext.get(cell).up('tr');
                var tbody = row.up('tbody');
                var rowIdx = tbody.query('tr', true).indexOf(row.dom);

                var records = view.up('grid').getPlugin('subtable').getAssociatedRecords(record);

                var subRecord = records[rowIdx];
                alert(subRecord);
            }
        }
    });
```

in HTML the grid seems:

```
<td class="x-grid-subtable-cell" style="width:100px">
    <div id="ext-element-5" class="x-grid-cell-inner">
        text
    </div>
</td>
```

si i tried `e.getTarget('.x-grid-subtable-cell')`, `e.getTarget('.x-grid-subtable-cell.x-grid-cell-inner')`, `e.getTarget('.x-grid-subtable-cell div')` but never i obtain the value inside the row of the sub-table where you doubleclick. What am i doing wrong?

(Maybe im doing a newbie question, but im learning javascript and its not yet my fort).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't have to go with DOMelements. Simply select the record of the row and use record.get('dataIndex') to receive the value.

Comment: `row` variable holds `Ext.Element` which points to clicked row. If you want do object call `row.dom`